# Stop text divs from overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two divs with text sit below each other and for them to automatically adjust to the height of the text but they seem to overlap like the text is ignoring the div. So far, it looks like this:

[image]

**My HTML is as follows:**

```
<div class="one_half_left"> 
   <div class="text1">Text</div>
   <div class="text2">XYZ</div>
</div>
```

**and the CSS is:**

```
.one_half_left { 
    margin: 40px 0 0px 40px; 
    float:left; 
    width:44%;
}

.text1{ 
    font-family:'NimbusSans', Helvetica, Arial; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-weight:800;    
    font-size:90px;
    color:#948e7d;
    min-height: 90px;
}

.text2{ 
    font-family:'NGBEC', Helvetica, Arial; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-weight:800;    
    font-size:140px;
    margin: 0 0 110px 0;
    color:#305d0b;
    min-height: 140px;
}
```

Can anybody suggest how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine. It is not overlapping

Comment: I have test your code and its working fine. you have to test it into different browsers.

Comment: .text2{overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Cannot reproduce....unless there is something you haven't mentioned - https://jsfiddle.net/1f6dz6yw/

Comment: The problem is not showing up with the code you posted. I've tried increasing the font-size in the stylesheet and the divs grow proportionally without overlapping. For producing the image you posted, I presume your divs are inheriting other css properties from somewhere in your page. For example position relative or fixed with a top value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that you are using a screen of really low resolution or you are not opening it in fullscreen. In that case changing browsers would do the trick.

Otherwise:

The thing I would do is to add a few `<br>` tag so as to separate the two divs without meddling with the CSS.

The code would now be:

```
<div class="one_half_left">
    <div class="text1">Text</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="text2">XYZ</div>
</div>
```

Leave the CSS untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey You can add clear:both; in both class:-
.one_half_left { 
    margin: 40px 0 0px 40px; 
    float:left; 
    width:44%;
}

.text1{ 
    font-family:'NimbusSans', Helvetica, Arial; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-weight:800;    
    font-size:90px;
    color:#948e7d;
    min-height: 90px;
    ***clear:both;***
}

.text2{ 
    font-family:'NGBEC', Helvetica, Arial; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-weight:800;    
    font-size:140px;
    margin: 0 0 110px 0;
    color:#305d0b;
    min-height: 140px;
    ***clear:both;***
}
```